# How to integrate IBM Connections business cards with an external application and target the styles easily?

Tags: css, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

In IBM Connections, when [integrating the Profiles business card](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+Documentation&action=openDocument&res_title=Integrating_the_Profiles_business_card_ic45&content=pdcontent) with an external application, using the `loadCssFiles=true` parameter has the positive effect of styling the hover activated Business Cards just like they would be within IBM Connections.  Unfortunately, it also completely messes up any page styling because it converts the body tag from

```
<body>
```

to

```
<body class="lotusui lotusui30dojo lotusui30_body lotusui30_fonts lotusui30 lotusSpritesOn">
<span id="semtagmenu" role="tooltip" style="...">...</span>
```

This has the unfortunate effect of restyling *everything on the page* **as well as** the hover activated Business Cards.

Applying the following snippet in Chrome console/Firebug rectifies the problem:

```
// all the offending CSS classess
var themLotusClasses = 'lotusui lotusui30dojo lotusui30_body lotusui30_fonts lotusui30 lotusSpritesOn';
// remove from the body tag
jQuery('body').removeClass(themLotusClasses);
// wrap *only* the Business Card HTML
jQuery('#semtagmenu').wrap('<span class="' + themLotusClasses + '"></span>');
```

This targets just the Business Cards, so the IBM Connections specific styles do not affect the rest of the page layout.

Is there a more elegant way of targeting **only** the `span#semtagmenu` node with all the extra Lotus classes?

I really want the Business Card styling. But I only want it applied to the Business Cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found that the easiest way is to simply duplicate the styles at

```
/connections/resources/web/_style?include=com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/base/standaloneVcard.css
```

and the enclosed sprite images, then use `loadCssFiles=false` instead.

This adds the classes:

```
lotusui lotusui30dojo lotusui30_body lotusui30_fonts lotusui30 lotusSpritesOn
```

to

```
<span id="semtagmenu" role="tooltip" style="...">...</span>
```

which in turn targets the hover triggered Business Card only for styles.